exclude the drawbale of unnecessary devices such as ldtrl/watch brought in by androidx.appcompat:appcompat through Gradle configuration
For example, exclude the drawbale of unnecessary devices such as ldtrl/watch brought in by androidx.appcompat:appcompat through Gradle configuration. Tried the following but none worked
1、
    aaptOptions{
        ignoreAssetsPattern 'drawable-nodpi-v4:drawable-mdpi-v4:drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17:drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17:' +
                'drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17:drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17:drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17:drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17' +
                ':drawable-watch-v20:layout-watch-v20'
    }

2、
packagingOptions {
    resources {
            excludes += ['res/drawable-nodpi-v4/**',
                         'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/**',
                         'res/drawable-ldrtl-watch-v17/**',
                         'res/layout-watch-v20/**',
            ]
        }
    }

3、
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                exclude 'res/drawable-nodpi-v4/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/drawable-ldrtl-watch-v17/**'
                exclude 'res/layout-watch-v20/**'
            }
        }
    }
}

4、I also tried the solution under this link, but it didn’t work
Using Build-specific aaptOptions in Android (for excluding specific Assets files/folders)
enter image description here
